# Slick2d StateBasedGame - WindowListener

Tags: slick2d

I've got a state based game in which i need to implement a WindowListener in one of the states. How do I do that? Couldn't find anything online.

Comment: What would you like the WindowListener to do?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have not found anything online is because Slick2d does not offer its own WindowListener! The WindowListener you may be thinking of is part of core java:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html

For java's WindowListener, there are plenty of online tutorials, but most require the use of something like Swing to be useful.

I would highly recommend this to use in your update() function, to check the status of the window. It will serve most needs in Slick2d (for example, I use it to detect to pause the game because the window has lost focus):

```
public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta)
        throws SlickException {
    if(!container.hasFocus()){
        //Pause the game here.
```